# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string while procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, oracle, procedure

I need your favor over resolve conversion issue.The code which i have like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [WORKFLOW_APP].[DIAGNOSISCD_CAR]
        @v_monthstr    CHAR ,
        @v_monthend    CHAR ,
        @v_year        CHAR ,
        @v_state_cd    CHAR ,
        @v_claim_key   CHAR ,
        @v_contractor  CHAR

DECLARE @v_makedatestr   VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @v_makedateend   VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @v_makedatestr  = '01-' + @v_monthstr + '-' + @v_year
SELECT @v_makedateend  = '01-' + @v_monthend + '-' + @v_year


SELECT @v_datebegin  = CONVERT(DATETIME, @v_makedatestr,105)----error
SELECT @v_dateend  = DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(M, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @v_makedateend ,105))), DATEADD(M, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @v_makedateend ,105)))---error
```

This code formed using tool and changed somewhere manual.

I am getting

> 'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.'

at "error" comment.

I tried using convert, cast functions but unable to resolve.

Any one suggest for error and write appropriate conversion code for that error.

I am converting an Oracle stored procedure to SQL Server 2005.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005.

What is the wrong from above code and what is the correct code ?

Any code ? ????////// for correct conversion

Comment: The year that your are receiving in the param `@v_year` is in 2 digits form?

Comment: A parameter of type `CHAR` = **1 character long string**. Is that *really* what you need? If not: define `CHAR(x)` (where `x` is the length) - and if it's more than 5-10 characters, use `VARCHAR(x)` instead!

Comment: @marc_s that's a really good point indeed

Answer (score 0):

The way you are converting the string to datetime can lead to different results in case you run the script in server with different culture related settings.

For datetime(s) as string, I recommend you follow the rule of building your string starting with the year, then month, and so on... `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
SELECT @v_makedatestr  = @v_year + '-' + @v_monthstr + '-01' 
SELECT @v_makedateend  = @v_year + '-' + @v_monthend + '-01'
```

Then you could just do a cast:

```
cast(@v_makedatestr as datetime);
cast(@v_makedateend as datetime);
```